# Activity sem Toolbar

Tags: android

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de tirar a toolbar que aparece em cima 'SeraAgora'. Na edição da view não aparece mas ao compilar volta à vida.
Como tirá-la de lá?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode configurar o tema da activity no manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <application ... >
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" ... >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Use o auto complete para ver as opções, tem várias que não vem com o toolbar, vai testando e escolha a que achar melhor, o único problema é que poderá mudar outros estilos da activity